# git install fails in Dockerfile

Tags: git, docker

I'm trying to pull the repository I'm working on while doing a docker build, so I followed [this tutorial](https://vsupalov.com/build-docker-image-clone-private-repo-ssh-key/) so I added in my `Dockerfile`

```
# this is our first build stage, it will not persist in the final image
FROM ubuntu as intermediate

# install git
RUN apt-get update \
    apt-get upgrade \
    apt-get install git

# add credentials on build
RUN mkdir ~/.ssh && ln -s /run/secrets/host_ssh_key ~/.ssh/id_rsa

# make sure your domain is accepted
RUN touch /root/.ssh/known_hosts
RUN ssh-keyscan github.org >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts

RUN git clone git@github.com:my-repo/myproject.git

FROM ubuntu
# copy the repository form the previous image
COPY --from=intermediate /your-repo /srv/your-repo
```

In my `docker-compose.yml` I added

```
secrets:
  host_ssh_key:
    file: ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

And I'm adding

```
secrets:
  - host_ssh_key
```

In one of the service.

Since this is only for my local use (I don't plan on deploying or using this for the production, I just want to test it out) it's fine to use it this way - if it'll work because currently the build fails at the git install stage with error

> E: The update command takes no arguments
>
> ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update  apt-get upgrade     apt-get install git' returned a non-zero code: 100

What am I missing?

Comment: Any chance you could accept an answer? So that it indicates to others that some solution was helpful for you. Would be great if you did on all your question that have answers.

Comment: Sure, even though in the end I did it differently. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Yeah its fine for local, and in fact not even a terrible idea for a dev server (But NOT staging or production!!!!)

Answer (score 131, accepted):

You are overanalyzing this. It's just a simple typo. Should be:

```
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install -y git
```

Those are 3 separate commands.

Comment: Still getting `The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update &&     apt-get upgrade &&     apt-get install git' returned a non-zero code: 1`

Comment: It's another issue, now `apt-get install` is waiting for you to submit the installation. So you should add `-y` after `install`. From your typo it seems to me like you don't know how to work with Linux. Maybe you should read everything around `apt-get`?

Comment: I'll try with the flag, but overall I'll probably just skip the git clone in the build process. At least that's what the devops is doing. I'm just testing the docker out, not my main area of expertise :D

Comment: in node:alpine:
RUN apk update && \
    apk upgrade && \
    apk add git

Comment: Run `update` after git installation. Try that one:
`RUN apt-get install --assume-yes git && apt-get update && apt-get clean all`

Answer (score 19):

For those working with `alpine` images, `RUN apk add --no-cache git` did the trick for me.

Comment: Thank You this saved the some time. Please why did you use ---no-cache?

Answer (score 14):

Some thoughts:

- 1. Replace `apt-get install git` with `apt-get install --assume-yes git`.  Without the `--assume-yes` it will prompt you for confirmation, which you are unable to give and it will be smart enough to figure that out and assume you meant "NO".
- 2. You added the ssh key, but did you confirm it was `0600`.  I would just copy it and specifically `chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa` to be sure.

Overall, your Dockerfile looks very clever and I got some fresh ideas from reading it.

Comment: Just read the tutorial - very good.  They use the `-y` switch.  I use the `--assume-yes` switch.  They are synonyms and I think that is what you are missing.  If you supplied a valid 'id_rsa' file then my second point is not applicable.

Comment: your edit to the question should be reverted, it clearly conflicts with author's intent.